# Rails 4 how to update join table of has many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, has-many-through, join

I am trying to update the boolean fields of a join table in a has many:through association in rails but the values never get inserted and the boolean fields stay at 0.

here are my models.

```
#image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :prodimgs
    has_many :products, through: :prodimgs
end

#product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :prodimgs
    has_many :images, through: :prodimgs

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :prodimgs
end

#prodimg.rb - this is the joining table
class Prodimg < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :products
    belongs_to :image

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

And here is the Prodimgs migration.

```
class Cre t.boolean :is_main
      t.boolean :is_medium
      t.boolean :is_thumbnail
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :image_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to update the is_main, is_medium and is_thumbnail fields from within a nested form in the products form.
Here is the form.

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>

  ...

  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>image</th>
        <th>Main Image</th>
        <th>Medium Image</th>
        <th>Thumb</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @product.images.collect(&:image).each do |image| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= image_tag image %></td>
          <td><%= f.radio_button :is_main, "false", :checked => false %></td>
          <td><%= f.radio_button :is_medium, "false", :checked => false %></td>
          <td><%= f.radio_button :is_thumbnail, "false", :checked => false %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>  
    </tbody>
  </table>

  ...


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= tinymce %>
```

So after I have uploaded and joined the images to the product I need to update the joining boolean fields with the radio boxes seen in the above code which will suggest that it is the main, medium or thumbnail image in the product image gallery.
I have tried using the cocoon gem to achieve the same thing but I was still unsuccessful at updating the boolean fields.
Here are the product_params in my products_controller.rb file.

```
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :shortdescription, :description, :sku, :status, :department_ids => [], :tag_ids => [], :image_ids => [], prodimgs_attributes: [:is_main, :is_medium, :is_thumbnail])
    end
```

Any input as to how I could solve this problem will be great!
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try it? What output are you looking at and how is it wrong?

Comment: Did you try in the console? What happens when running `save`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. when I run `save` I get `undefined local variable or method`